# jar file creation - library dependecy

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

i want to create a jar file of my java web application.

This web application has so many jar files related to this. so all am including in the build path. And when the time of jar file creation from eclipse,even if i had checked the checkbox for exporting the class files and resources option, the generated jar file doesn't have those library files. So when am trying to execute the jar file from command line option by using

```
java -jar myJarfile.jar
```

it will throw error like `NoClassDefFoundError` , can anyone  help me to solve the issue.?

How can i generate the jar with all dependencies.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really be including external dependencies in your jar.  Just bundle up your code into your jar and specify the dependencies at runtime.

java -jar myJarfile.jar -cp someDependency.jar

Comment: Are you sure you're including all the dependencies in the classpath?  And have you defined the Main-Class attribute within the manifest file?  Could you post the stacktrace?